# Git tag condition not working on Github Actions

Tags: git, github, intellij-idea, github-actions

I want to use action-gh-release on my github action, and my .yml is like:

```
...

release:
  needs: assemble
  if: startsWith(github.ref, 'refs/tags/v')
  runs-on: ubuntu-latest

  steps:
  - uses: actions/checkout@v2
  - uses: actions/download-artifact@v2
    with:
      name: my-target
      path: target/
  - name: Release
    uses: softprops/action-gh-release@v1
    with:
      files: target/*.jar
    env:
      GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
```

And assemble step is success, I use Intellij to add git tag and push, and I check diff
[image]

And I use echo to check github.ref, and I got:

[image]

And release step is skipped
[image]

And no tag build
[image]

Is my .yml have some wrong? Or I need to use different IDE to push tag?

Comment: Typically you'll see *two* builds when you push a tag; one for the tag, one for the regular branch commit (e.g. https://github.com/textbook/express-msgpack/actions/runs/673039979, https://github.com/textbook/express-msgpack/actions/runs/673036781). You need to look at the other one.

Comment: @jonrsharpe but I did not see any other build, all builds are with regular branch commit, as edit image

Comment: Do you have something like `on.push.tags` configured?

Comment: @JeffScottBrown I found the problem, I use the on command with branches: [ master ], thanks your answer!

Comment: I'm having same issues as well. could you please post the full `on:` for the working workflow?